# Getting elapsed time between updates in wxWidgets

Tags: user-interface, wxwidgets

I am builing an interactive application using the latest wxWidgets(3.0.1) and OpenGL(3.3) on Windows. I have gotten to the point where I have a wxGLcanvas rendering onto a wxPanel and it works fine. The rendering is done in the paint event for that GLcanvas. However, I now want to perform simulations with an accurate delta time between updates.

So essentially I would like some sort of functionality that would allow me to have a method like

```
void Update(float dt)
{
  // Update simulation with accurate time-step
}
```

I have come across timers but I'm not sure how I could incorporate it into my application to get an accurate **dt**. Some have mentioned creating a separate thread for that panel to update independently from the rest of the application. Is this an option and roughly how is it implemented if that is the case?

Answer (score 0):

Timer precision should be good enough to achieve at least ~50 FPS, so they should be good enough for your purpose. You need to use a timer to get regular calls to your timer event handler which can then use a more accurate method (as timers are not guaranteed to be perfectly regular) to determine whether an updated is needed, e.g. using `wxDateTime::UNow()`, and queue a `Refresh()` in this case.

Notice that you still will not be able to guarantee regular window refreshes using normal GUI frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

What operating system are you using?  There is no way in Windows to guarantee an accurate time for an event.  Unix, however is a real time operating system ( RTOS ) and it is possible to guarantee event times.

What range of delta times do you care about?  The distinction between RTOS's and Windows only matters for times less than 2 to 3 milliseconds ( unless windows becomes ridiculously overloaded ) Since any worthwhile 3D scene will take more that 3 milliseconds to render, this is probably a non-issue!

Of most significance in this kind of question is the response time of human vision.  Watching a dynamic diagram such as a plot, people are unaware of any refresh rate faster than 300 ms.  If you want to attempt a video realistic effect, you might need a refresh rate approaching 25 ms - but then your problem will not be the accuracy of your timer, but the speed of your scene rendering.  So, once again, this is a non-issue.

Comment: I'm using windows. Ive edited the question to display ths OS in question

Comment: I'd like to have rougly a 16-17 ms between updates so 60fps essentially

Comment: Can you render your scene in 16 ms?

Comment: Yeah I can.. Is it a matter of creating a timer and calling timer.Start(16) ??

Comment: Yes.  Your timer event handler will be called every 16 ms +/- 5 ms.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/571935/16582

Comment: So in the timer event handler I could call update like this Update((float)(16/1000)).

Comment: Yes, I suppose.  ( Note that the integer division will pass 0 to the update method - you would be better to just use a constant.)